# WPF Dependency Property In Nested User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have the following WPF Control which is used to Show A Text With An Image Beside it

XAML Code

```
<UserControl x:Class="WFWorkSpaceWPF.UserControls.StackedImageTextCtl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="StackedImageText"
         >
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=StackedImageText, Path=ImageSource}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=StackedImageText, Path=Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

CS

```
 public partial class StackedImageTextCtl : UserControl
{
    public StackedImageTextCtl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region "Properties"
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(StackedImageTextCtl), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(StackedImageTextCtl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion
}
```

In my project i want to reuse this control in other three user controls where it will be added as a part of these controls, As you see that the StackedImageTextCtl exposes Two Properties (Text and Image Source) that the parent User Controls needs to provide to it and these three controls will take the value from the container window throw XAML, I know that One of the ways to do so is to replicate defining the properties in each of these three user control and Using AddOwner functionality, but i am looking for a more better approach that won't require any repeat in code, can anyone please direct me to such way?.

Comment: Have you thought of inheritance???

Comment: Inheriting of what? of the StackedImageTextCtl user control you mean? 
I don't know how it will work in this case, as the user control will be used as a content inside these other controls

Comment: Yes, exactly. Inherit and also have it as content. In the end you will have two instances anyways. It seems to me that StackedImageTextCtl shall be base class. For example Person is base class for Teacher and Student. It makes sense.

Comment: Maybe if you post some more code concerning where is it supposed to be used?

Comment: @Bizz I am planning to use it as a content inside user controls that have Buttons, for example UCImageButton will have a Button and inside the content of the Button i will add StackedImageTextCtl ,another control UCImageToggleButton will have a ToggleButton(A Telerik WPF control) and inside it's content will be a StackedImageTextCtl and these UCImageButton and UCImageToggleButton will be used in a window that should pass the Source and Text to them and they will pass it to StackedImageTextCtl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your UserControl:

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="16"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and its code:

in addition to `Text` and `ImageSource`, there is `State` which represents the `Add/Edit/delete` state of this control, and there is `StackCtlState` which is an attached property and when attached to a `FrameworkElement` it represents the `Add/Edit/delete` state of that control.

```
    public StackedImageTextCtl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    //Text Dependency Property
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(StackedImageTextCtl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    //ImageSource Dependency Property
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(StackedImageTextCtl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    //State Dependency Property
    public AddEditDelete State
    {
        get { return (AddEditDelete)GetValue(StateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(AddEditDelete), typeof(StackedImageTextCtl), new UIPropertyMetadata(AddEditDelete.Add));

    public static AddEditDelete GetStackCtlState(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (AddEditDelete)obj.GetValue(StackCtlStateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetStackCtlState(DependencyObject obj, AddEditDelete value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(StackCtlStateProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StackCtlStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StackCtlState", typeof(AddEditDelete), typeof(StackedImageTextCtl), new UIPropertyMetadata(AddEditDelete.Add));
```

I also define an enum:

```
public enum AddEditDelete { Add, Edit, Delete }
```

In Window xaml:

Each `Button` or `ToggleButton` have their attached property `StackCtlState` set to the desired value and also have their style set to one of styles for `Button` or `ToggleButton`.

Then these styles add a `StackedImageTextCtl` to the contents of styled button/togglebutton in the proper way that resources can be reused. (if you set just Content and don't set Template instead it will only show the contents of the last `Button` or last `ToggleButton`) The added `StackedImageTextCtl` has a `State` equal to the attached value of its `TemplatedParent` which is `Button` or `ToggleButton`.

At last the style uses `Trigger` to set the values for Text and Image, based on `State` of the `StackedImageTextCtl`.

```
<Window...
     xmlns:myNamespace="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">


<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="State" Value="Add">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="ADD"/>
                <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="/blue_1.jpg"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="State" Value="Edit">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="EDIT"/>
                <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="/blue_2.jpg"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="State" Value="Delete">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="DELETE"/>
                <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="/blue_3.jpg"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="stackButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Button>
                        <myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl State="{TemplateBinding myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl.StackCtlState}"/>
                    </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="stackToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton>
                        <myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl State="{TemplateBinding myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl.StackCtlState}"/>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource stackButtonStyle}" myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl.StackCtlState="Add"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource stackButtonStyle}" myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl.StackCtlState="Edit"/>
    <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource stackToggleButtonStyle}" myNamespace:StackedImageTextCtl.StackCtlState="Delete"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: this is the correct usage if i am not providing different images, i will reuse the button and toggle buttons in different windows(multiple times per window) and each window will provide a different text and image for each button. hence this is why i am looking for a proper way to provide the image/text from the window to each instance of the button controls and their StackedImageTextCtl instance.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. I edited my answer. see if that's what you need.

Comment: i will check it out, but i have a question suppose the let us say the ToggleButton button is added multiple times to the window and each instance will have it's own image and text, how the above will come in play?

Comment: I changed my answer, I hope this helps.